# Redirecionar usuário caso uma classe seja removida

Tags: javascript, condição, redirecionamento-de-url

##### Criei um tema e gostaria que, se (somente se) os créditos contidos dentro da classe `creditos` forem removidos ou adulterados por alguém, a página será redirecionada para o meu portfólio.

Encontrei muitos códigos, porém, este que escolhi está dando erro, pois ele redireciona mesmo que o link esteja correto.
Ou seja, se eu colocar **Design por `<a href='endereço falso...`** ou estiver exatamente igual ao código abaixo, ele redireciona o site do cliente para meu portfólio do mesmo jeito.

```html
<div id="creditos">
   <span class='creditos'>Design por <a href='https://meuportfolio.com' target='_blank'>Nome do designer.</a></span>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($('span.creditos') != 'https://meuportfolio.com') {
         window.location = 'https://meuportfolio.com'
      } else {
         return False;
      }
   });
</script>
```

Como corrigir?

Comment: Se o cliente remover os créditos, ele vai remover o redirecionamento também, é irrelevante isso.
A única solução viável é forçar uma licença.

Comment: De fato é irrelevante isto, pois se o cliente tem a possibilidade de remover a classe `creditos` consequentemente ele conseguirá remover o script. Vi algo semelhante em um post, onde o proprietário criou algumas funções e APIs e hospedou em sua plataforma, assim quando o usuário importava o script (*o código era todo ofuscado*) não era possível remover uma tag `meta` do html, pois o mesmo ficava verificando se a mesma não foi alterada, se for alterada, ele desconstruía o html e exibia uma mensagem de erro onde sinalizava que a tag `meta` foi alterada! (*obrigava a manter-la por uso do script*)

Comment: Sim, eu estou ciente disso (e já estou cuidando dos detalhes de licença também), mas ainda assim, eu gostaria de saber como fazer esse código funcionar para fazer isso JUNTO com a licença.

Comment: você pode aplicar o mesmo exemplo acima..

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Antes de qualquer coisa, você deve considerar que quando você faz essa tratativa do lado do cliente, é 100% "burlável".
Bom, levando isso em conta, vamos a solução:

1. Verifique se não há outro momento que essa classe esteja sendo declarada em um spam
2. Verificar se chamou a biblioteca Jquery

Agora vamos consertar o código:

```
 <div id="creditos">
   <span class='creditos'>Design por <a href='https://google.com' target='_blank'>Nome do designer.</a></span>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        let c = $('span.creditos > a');
        let link = c.attr("href")
        console.log(link)
      if (link != 'https://google.com') {
         window.location = 'https://google.com'
      }
   });
</script>
```

[***DEMO***](https://jsfiddle.net/tubx4fs2/)

Comment: Olá, infelizmente ela continua redirecionando para a minha página, independente de estar correto o link ou não :/

Comment: confira  https://jsfiddle.net/tubx4fs2/

Inclusive editei a resposta adicionando esse link!
Perceba que não está redirecionando, pois o link está igual:
tente mudar o link e executar novamente, ele vai redirecionar!

Comment: Deu certo agora! Muito obrigada!